# Issues running Python script using crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I am using a Macbook Pro and the normal terminal.
I have written a python script that works and runs when I run it either in VScode or via terminal using `python3 script.py` (when I navigate to the location of the script using `cd`).
I have tried learning a bit about crontab and had an attempt below based on online guides but for some reason it doesn't seem to execute my script.
My crontab code, accessed from terminal with `crontab -e`:

```
30 16 * * * usr/bin/python3 User/Person/Documents/script.py
```

As well as:

```
30 16 * * * usr/local/bin/python3 User/Person/Documents/script.py
```

None of which I've had any success. To my knowledge, the cron job should run my python3 script at 4:30pm but it doesn't do that.

I have also tried adding a `cd User/Person/Documents && usr/local/bin/python3` before the script to see if my navigation had any problems but alas not.

Comment: `usr/bin/python3` should probably be `/usr/bin/python3`, assuming you intend the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nick ODell's comment, `User/Person/Documents/script.py` should probably be `/Users/Person/Documents/script.py`

On MacOS, the path in the question does not match the path structure of the OS. If one attempts to `cd` to a path that doesn't exist, or to execute a script from a path that doesn't exist, it will not work.